# Как получить данные с родительского класса?

Tags: c++, классы

Я совсем новенький в c++, то что я написал это плохо или нет? Есть ли другие способы получить данные с родительского класса?

```
class A
{
public:
 virtual double func1() { return mVar1; }

private:
 double mVar1;
}


class B : public A
{
public:
 double func1();

private:
 double mVar2;
}

B::func1()
{
 return A::func1() * mVar2;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря, чего вы хотите добиться. Этот код компилируется. Делает то, что вы описываете. Ещё можно сделать переменную `A::mVar1` не `private`, а `protected`, тогда не нужна будет отдельная функция `A::func1` Переменная будет доступна в классе-наседнике:

```
class A
{
public:
  virtual double func1() { return mVar1; }

protected:
  double mVar1;
};


class B : public A
{
public:
  double func1();

private:
  double mVar2;
};

double B::func1()
{
  return mVar1 * mVar2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Как получить данные с родительского класса?**
> В случае, если производный (дочерний) класс (**class B**) получает доступ непосредственно к данным родительского (базового) класса (**class A**) - это очень плохой пример для практики так как нарушается один из основных принципов ООП - инкапсуляция.
> Инкапсуляция подразумевает возможность для класса B иметь доступ к данным класса А только через методы (функции), описываемые в разделах **public / protected** класса А, но никак не напрямую. Иначе любой производный класс может в любой момент изменить данные базового класса, что приводит к ошибкам, которые трудно отследить и исправить.